# Javascript variable as function name

Tags: javascript

```
const self = {
        element: document.querySelector(selector),
        html: () => self.element,
        on: (event, callback) => {
            self.element.addEventListener(event, callback);
        },
        style: {
            alignContent: (property) => {
                return (property === null) ? self.element.style.alignContent : self.element.style.alignContent = property;
            }
     }
}
```

I am trying to make it so I have quick access to all CSS style properties with jQuery like selectors it should work as: `select('h1').style.alignContent('center')`, but the problem is that I would have to make a seperate function for each style property in order for this method to work, is there a way to solve this problem without duplicating a lot of code?

```
//Duplication example
color: (property) => {
  return (property === null) ? self.element.style.color : self.element.style.color = property;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is with a `Proxy` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)):

```js
let elemWrapper = selector => {
  let element = document.querySelector(selector);
  return {
    element,
    html: () => element,
    on: (event, callback) => {
      element.addEventListener(event, callback);
    },
    style: new Proxy({}, {
      get: (obj, prop) => {
        // The user called a function named "prop"
        // We need to return a function that sets the style property named "prop"
        return cssValue => element.style[prop] = cssValue;
      }
    })
  };
};

let bodyElem = elemWrapper('body');
bodyElem.style.backgroundColor('cyan');
```

Here to prove the concept I've set the `body` element's background colour using a dynamically named function.

The big downside to this approach is the poor performance of Proxies (an excellent read on Proxy performance is available [here](http://thecodebarbarian.com/thoughts-on-es6-proxies-performance)).

This means it may be quicker to simply compile a list of all css property names, and define a function for each (never using Proxies). The following code compiles all css property names, to serve as a starting point:

```js
console.log(Object.keys(document.body.style));
```

Comment: Why does returning a function cssValue give me the argument?

Comment: To clarify - are you asking about the return value of `bodyElem.style.backgroundColor('...')`?

Comment: ```return cssValue => element.style[prop] = cssValue;``` this bit

Comment: That function takes only a css value, and sets it under a given css property name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to intercept all attempts to get a property.

```js
let selector = '#test';
const self = {
    element: document.querySelector(selector),
    html: () => self.element,
    on: (event, callback) => {
        self.element.addEventListener(event, callback);
    },
    style: new Proxy(Object.create(null), {
        get(target, prop, receiver) {
            if (self.element.style.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                return val => {
                    if (val != null) {
                        self.element.style[prop] = val;
                    } else {
                        return self.element.style[prop];
                    }
                }
            }
            throw Error("No such property exists: " + prop);
        }
    })
};
self.style.color('red')
console.log("Color:", self.style.color());
```

```html
<div id="test">
This is a test
</div>
```

You can also wrap this into a general function like so:

```js
const getEnhancedElement = arg => {
  const element = /Element/.test(Object.prototype.toString.call(arg)) ? arg
     : document.querySelector(arg);//accept a HTMLElement or a selector
  return {
    element,
    html: () => element,
    on: (event, callback) => {
      element.addEventListener(event, callback);
    },
    style: new Proxy(Object.create(null), {
      get(target, prop) {
        if (element.style.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          return val => {
            if (val != null) {//set value
              element.style[prop] = val;
            } else {//get value
              return element.style[prop];
            }
          }
        }
        throw Error("No such property exists: " + prop);
      }
    })
  };
};
let test = getEnhancedElement("#test");
test.style.color('red')
console.log("Color:", test.style.color());
test.style.textAlign('center');
```

```html
<div id="test">
  This is a test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have something like this:

```js
style: {
    chnageStyle: (propertyName, propertyVal) => {
        return (propertyName === null) ? self.element.style[propertyName] : self.element.style[propertyName] = propertyVal;
    }
}
```

Then you can call this:

```js
style.changeStyle('alignContent','center');
style.changeStyle('color','orange');
```